# Strange PDO Behavior Concerning Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters, integer

Preface: I'll try to be as thorough as possible, although I'm not sure whether all of this information is relevant.

I'm interacting with a MySQL database (5.0.7*) via PDO (PHP 5.3.*) with the following attributes set:

- PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE
- PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

I'm using a database table storing ratings which is described as such:

```
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| userID     | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL |                   |       |
| articleID  | varchar(32) | NO   | MUL |                   |       |
| rating     | tinyint(2)  | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
```

I'm doing a search on a rating based upon the article and the user ID values:

```
SELECT rating FROM member_ratings WHERE userID = :uid AND articleID = :aid
```

I'm then setting named parameters by reference:

```
-> bindParam(':uid', $_COOKIE['userID']);
-> bindParam(':aid', $_POST['aid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The **problem** is that while the `execute()` function returns `true`, the variable holding the `prepare` function returns false, and calling something like `-> rowCount()` throws an error, indicating that PDO has errored out. However, no `PDOException` has been thrown, nor does `-> errorInfo()` provide anything other than an error of 0000.

Querying in the actual MySQL CLI returns the actual value that I'm searching for:

```
| rating |
+--------+
|      2 |
```

What I find most interesting is that if I remove either of the two parameters from the equation:

```
SELECT rating FROM member_ratings WHERE articleID = :aid
-> bindParam(':aid', $_POST['aid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

SELECT rating FROM member_ratings WHERE userID = :uid
-> bindParam(':uid', $_COOKIE['userID']);
```

I get a plethora of results. I'm not sure what this indicates at all. For now, my solution is thus:

```
-> prepare("SELECT uid FROM member_ratings WHERE userID = :uid AND articleID = " . 
            filter_var($_POST['aid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT))
```

Which returns the correct value when I throw a `rowCount()`, `fetchObject()` and so forth. I came to this conclusion, as I know `aid` is always supposed to be an integer, but userID could be alphanumeric.

In addition to the above, I've tried:

- Setting values as variables before passing them
- Tried it without `PDO::PARAM_INT`
- Using 1-based parameters (?) instead of named parameters (:)
- Removing my error mode attributes

I'm not sure why it's failing, and I've done a bit of digging as well (although I'm also not exactly sure what to search for.) With E_ALL I'm not getting any errors whatsoever. Any ideas?

### Edit

**It seems that using bindValue allows this to work, whereas using bindParam doesn't. This means that I cannot use bindParam to its fullest extent:**

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#80285
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php#115510

**Does anyone know why?**

Comment: Uhm. Have you tried doing a is_integer of the var and do a cast? PhP can cast variable, normally it's not needed but it can be worth try it.

Comment: Always use unnamed parameters ? unless you have a pressing need to use named parameters.

Comment: @marco-mura, I was actually using another method of determining whether it's an integer:

`ctype_digit(strval($variable))`

@david-strachan It doesn't work with named or unnamed parameters. Could you explain why?

Comment: why not use php standard code... is_integer($var)?

Comment: @MarcoMura, the docs for `ctype_digit` indicate that it "checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical." Combined with `strval` which evaluates whatever is passed in as a string, you can determine if it's an integer even if the returning function hasn't cast it as such. Even if I did use `is_integer()` it doesn't solve the original problem, unfortunately.